# independence of product of independent random variables with one of the variables

Tags: independence

Take random variables A and B, which are independent.

Is it the case that AB (product) is independent of B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No of course not. For those to be independent you would need the conditional probability $P(A \times B | B)$ to equal $P(A \times B)$, which also means

$$ \int_B P(A \times B | B=b) db = P(A \times B | B) $$

That's called the law of total probability. I'm abusing notation here but you get the idea.

The only way that could happen, as far as I can tell, is if $B$ has a degenerate distribution.